# Difference between K-S manual test and K-S test with R?

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

On the Internet there is an example of k-s test being applied relative to distribution of number of bird varieties over different five hour periods.
The observed distribution was:

```
a=c(0,1,1,9,4)
```

The expected distribution (if there is no difference between the five hours) could be:

```
b=c(3,3,3,3,3)
```

After I found the two cumulate distributions, I calculated manually, D = 0,4667 (a value that is similar with the internet). 
But if I try to use R, I find a different value of D:

```
> a=c(0,1,1,9,4)

> b=c(3,3,3,3,3)

> ks.test(a,b)

Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data: a and b 

D = 0.6, p-value = 0.3291

alternative hypothesis: two-sided .......
```

- What is leading to the difference between my manual calculation and result that R gives?

Comment: @Massimo, please provide link, internet is a large place.

Comment: www.sixsigmain.it/ebook/Capu7-15.html

Comment: sorry, in italian language

Comment: @Massimo, @Henry answer is the correct one. The data in your link comes in tabular format, how many times certain values are observed, `ks.test` expects simple sample, not the table, hence the difference.

Comment: @mpiktas, and then ... how write with R for compare a with b?

Comment: @Massimo, is @Henry answer not clear?

Answer (score 6):

You are testing a different thing.

While you think `c(0,1,1,9,4)` means you are looking at 0 values of one, 1 value of two, 1 value of three, 9 values of four, and 4 values of five, R thinks you are looking at one value of 0, two values of 1, one value of 9, and one value of 4.

To get D = 0.4667..., try the rather verbose

```
ks.test( c(2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5), 
         c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5) )
```

giving

```
    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test 

D = 0.4667, p-value = 0.07626 
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: Wow, good sleuthing - I would have never thought of that. Based on the short description of the data, it seems unlikely that this was the intention (especially for `b`), but clearly that's what the online calculator is doing.

Comment: @Henry +1 for replicating the value of KS test. I would like to add that I suspect that R does not think the way you suggested. `c(0,1,1,9,4)` is simply the vector with values 0,1,1,9,4. I do not find any suggestion in ks.test manual page to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @mpiktas: that is what I meant by "one value of 0, two values of 1, one value of 9, and one value of 4".

Comment: @Henry: only now I understand. While I wrote the number of bird, R wanted the distribution of the hours.

Comment: To get to the data format used here... rep(1:5, c(0,1,1,9,4)).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test is probably incorrect for your situation. I assume you want to test whether the distribution of the number bird sightings is uniform (constant accross time). A chi-square goodness-of-fit test would be the simplest solution for that.

Second, the R-produced value of 0.6 seems correct to me: at $x=2.5$, $F_a(x)=0.6$, while $F_b(x)=0$.