# Even more with the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with R software

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

This follows on from the previous question on [differences between K-S manual test and K-S test with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10030/difference-between-k-s-manual-test-and-k-s-test-with-r).

My frequency sample was

```
a=c(0,1,1,4,9).
```

Then the observed sample is

```
 obs=c(2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)
```

The expected sample is then

```
exp=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
```

I hope you agree.

First, I use `ks.test`, like another time:

```
ks.test(obs,exp)

data:  oss and att

D = 0.4667, p-value = 0.07626
```

Then, I use the ks.test the other way:

The expected distribution can be the uniform. Do you agree?

And then:

```
ks.test(obs, "punif", 0,5)

data:  obs 

D = 0.6667, p-value = 3.239e-06
```

#### Question

- Why do the two approaches give different results?

Comment: I added the `multinomial` tag because it will provide useful related links at the right of this page.

Comment: @whuber Thank for this. I agree with you that mine is a discrete distribution but R don't know this and, for that, it is not correct the application of ks.test (for 1 sample) in this situation. I don't sure to undestand the second part.But my question was different and, perhaps, I don't explain very well. In others worlds:

Comment: ... In the first 5 hours I see 15 birds. In the first hour, nothing. In the second and third only 1, in the fourth 9 birds and in the fifth 4 birds. Then the frequency of the birds is (0,1,1,9,4) and the expected is (3,3,3,3,3). In the other question suggested the others samples: obs=c(2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5): number 1 there is not because in the first hour no birds. Number 2 and 3 only one time because in the second and third hour there is only one bird....

Comment: @whuber Then I need to know (and I ask) if there is a way for use the ks.test for one sample and get the same result. R know the uniform discrete distribution?..... Thank

Answer (score 6):

The first is a **two-sample test**; the second is a **one-sample test against a continuous distribution**.  Neither is used correctly:

- The two-sample test views both sets of data as being *data*, but your "expected sample" is not data, it's a theoretical reference.  It is not subject to any variation.  The two-sample test thinks that it *can* vary.  That's why the p-value is so large.
- The reference distribution used in the one-sample test is a continuous uniform distribution between 0 and 5.  However, these data look discrete: from the way they are given, it appears they can attain only the values 1, 2, ..., 5.  Because the one-sample test doesn't know this, its p-value is probably too small.

At least this lets us infer that the correct p-value should lie somewhere between 0.076 and 3.2e-06.  Because that doesn't settle the question, let's analyze further.

To get a sense of whether the data (0, 1, 1, 4, 9) differ significantly from the discrete uniform frequencies (3, 3, 3, 3, 3), view the latter as describing a five-sided die.  What are the chances that in 0+1+...+9 = 15 tosses of this die that at least one value would appear 9 or more times?  The events (1 appears 9 or more times), (2 appears 9 or more times), ..., (5 appears 9 or more times) are mutually exclusive--no two of them can hold at once--so their probabilities add.  Because the die is uniform each of these five events has the same probability.  We can compute the chance that a 5 comes up 9 or more times by viewing it like tosses of a biased coin: a 5 has a 1/5 chance; a non-5 has a 4/5 chance.  The chance of 9 or more 5's therefore equals

$$\binom{15}{9}(1/5)^9(4/5)^6 + \binom{15}{10}(1/5)^{10}(4/5)^5 + \cdots + \binom{15}{15}(1/5)^{15}(1/4)^0.$$

This value is approximately 0.000785.  Multiplying by 5 gives .00392 = 0.39%, still quite small.  Thus this set of frequencies is unlikely to have arisen through a single experiment in which each of the values has an equal chance of arising.

Comment: Very elucidating answer for us non-stats guys/gals.